# When updating a MongoDB collection's document structure in a forEach loop, the behavior appears inconsistent and incorrect

Tags: mongodb

I need to restructure the documents in my database. Specifically, I have an array which contains a set of subdocuments, but I need to turn this array into an object using the subdocuments' id strings as the field names (I'm aware that this is a non-ideal structure, but there is a reason for this decision due partly to issues with legacy data and efficiency concerns).

My documents look roughly like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(" . . . "),
    my_target_field: [
        {
            _id: ObjectId("a"),
            some_array: [ {...}, {...} ]
        },
        {
            _id: ObjectId("b"),
            some_array: [ {...}, {...}, {...} ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I need is something roughly like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(" . . . "),
    my_target_field: {
        a: {
            _id: ObjectId("a"),
            some_array: [ {...}, {...} ]
        },
        b: {
            _id: ObjectId("b"),
            some_array: [ {...}, {...}, {...} ]
        }
    }
}
```

My `forEach` call currently looks like this:

```
db.my_collection.find({
    some_invalid_field: {$exists: false}
}).forEach(function(doc) {
    var original_arr = doc.my_target_field ? doc.my_target_field : [];
    var converted_obj = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < original_arr.length; i++) {
        var cur_sub_doc = original_arr[i];
        converted_obj[cur_sub_doc._id.valueOf()] = cur_sub_doc;
    }

    db.my_collection.update({
        _id: doc._id
    }, {$set: {
        my_target_field: converted_obj
    }});
```

This *sort of* works, but I've found that a lot of documents that it should be converting properly actually end up losing data and end up looking like:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(" . . . "),
    my_target_field: { }
}
```

This is expected of documents that have empty arrays, but even documents that have non-empty arrays occasionally end up looking like this. This occurs despite other documents updating correctly and having the expected structure. Furthermore, the subdocuments within the array aren't missing ObjectIds, and if I revert to a backup and attempt using the script on just the documents that previously failed, it seems like those documents don't have any problems, so this behavior isn't even consistent.

Any insight regarding what could be causing this problem would be greatly appreciated. I'm seriously at a loss as to what could be the cause.

Comment: Which MongoDB version are you using?

Comment: 3.2, I believe.

Comment: @dnickless 3.2.12, specifically.

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with your above code. So I'm suggesting the "last resort" option to add some debug output. You could, e.g. check if `original_arr.length` is equal to zero and then print out the document or so... With a newer MongoDB version you *might* be able to retrieve the correct format directly using stuff like `$objectToArray` and `$arrayToObject`.

Comment: Unfortunately I've already logged output and I can't seem to find the problem. If I don't get any answers that provide the insight I need, I'll probably just attempt the update on the server side to try to circumvent whatever problem is getting in the way. This is far from being ideal as it's much slower than I would like due to the increased network overhead, but I'll do whatever needs to be done. I certainly hope to see an answer regardless because I would like to avoid banging my head against this particular wall in the future :)

Comment: One thing I've seen - not sure if that could be the case here, though, is an infinite recursion of a find method that would constantly create new documents which would be found again and so on. But you're "only" updating stuff here. If that bugger bites you then your script should probably not run to its end, though. To cirdumvent this you'd need to materialize your find cursor into an array or something first and then iterate. Depending on your data volume that could require significant memory so chunking would probably be the way to go.